# How to get rid of Java exception error while running Picard (bioinformatics) tool inside a shell script?

Tags: java, bash, shell, java-8

I have installed a bioinformatics tool `Picard 2.20` in my HPC cluster to run some metrics on my genome aligned files. The Picard 2.20 requires JDK 1.8 and our cluster has 1.6 so I installed `JDK 1.8` in my home directory of cluster and set the environment variables for both `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY` so that it works properly. I checked both jdk_1.8 and Picard to be installed correctly as they show up the custom -help page while invoking the necessary commands. Infact when I am running it inside a the directory of my input files as well, they are running properly however if I want to run it through a shell script and qsub it am getting java error.

This works

```
java -Xmx2g -jar /home/vdas/tools/picard-tools-2.2.0/picard.jar AddOrReplaceReadGroups I=Aligned.out.sam O=rg_added_sorted.bam SO=coordinate RGID=S_13_O1_122_S12919 RGLB=PairedEnd RGPL=Illumina RGPU=C7MC6ACXX RGSM=S_13_O1_122_S12919
```

But this does not

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#$ -N picard_run
#$ -cwd
#$ -e err_picard_run.log
#$ -o out_picard_run.log
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -M abc.def@xyz.com
#$ -m bea
#$ -l h_vmem=40G

samfile=/data/GT/OvaCa_project/RNA-Seq/STAR_run/2pass
#cd $samfile

java -Xmx2g -jar /home/vdas/tools/picard-tools-2.2.0/picard.jar AddOrReplaceReadGroups I=$samfile/Aligned.out.sam O=$samfile/rg_added_sorted.bam SO=coordinate RGID=S_13_O1_122_S12919 RGLB=PairedEnd RGPL=Illumina RGPU=C7MC6ACXX RGSM=S_13_O1_122_S12919 

echo "done"
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: picard/cmdline/PicardCommandLine : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: picard.cmdline.PicardCommandLine. Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: picard/cmdline/PicardCommandLine : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: picard.cmdline.PicardCommandLine. Program will exit.
```

How to work it up? What am I missing? Is it something with class path?

Comment: You may add a command line "which java" before the java call and maybe a "java -version" to see the used java installation.

Comment: `echo $PATH
/home/vdas/tools/jdk1.8.0_77/bin: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/vdas/tools/jdk1.8.0_77/lib:` Then it is fine right?

Comment: Does it work if you run your command (not the script) in the repository of your script? `java ... I=/data/GT/OvaCa_project/RNA-Seq/STAR_run/2pass/Aligned.out.sam O=/data/GT/OvaCa_project/RNA-Seq/STAR_run/2pass/rg_added_sorted.bam ...`

Comment: yes that is what I mentioned earlier in the query that Java installation is fine as the command runs without putting inside a shell script but I want to perform more than one task so I want to run it inside a shell script and execute it via qsub

Comment: Yes but you mentioned it works in the directory of your input files, but does it work as well with absolute paths, so in another directory? If the answer is yes, then try `java -version` in your script before your command as Konrad suggested.

Comment: And maybe check the JAVA_HOME environment setting.

Comment: if my `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are already set in my bash_profile for the version of java then why should I have to again set `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 2):

The key is to set `$JAVA_HOME/bin` before `$PATH` in either your `.bashrc` or your SGE qsub shell script like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/vdas/tools/jdk1.8.0_77
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This will execute the correct version `jdk1.8.0_77` first.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version and installation of java you're using and also set JAVA_HOME variable to your java 8 installation.

I suggest you to launch your java program this way into the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#$ -N picard_run
#$ -cwd
#$ -e err_picard_run.log
#$ -o out_picard_run.log
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -M abc.def@xyz.com
#$ -m bea
#$ -l h_vmem=40G

samfile=/data/GT/OvaCa_project/RNA-Seq/STAR_run/2pass
#cd $samfile

c=$(java -Xmx2g -jar /home/vdas/tools/picard-tools-2.2.0/picard.jar AddOrReplaceReadGroups I=$samfile/Aligned.out.sam O=$samfile/rg_added_sorted.bam SO=coordinate RGID=S_13_O1_122_S12919 RGLB=PairedEnd RGPL=Illumina RGPU=C7MC6ACXX RGSM=S_13_O1_122_S12919)

echo "done"
```

Comment: I have checked the java version and checked my `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. They both show Java 8. Can you explain what is this doing as you put

Comment: I had very similar error once and it worked this way in RedHat 5

Comment: not a very clean way, i found a solution which is not so clean, I tried to see the `java -version` and `which java` inside the shell script and it redirects to the root which is lower so I just put a `java_home=/path/java8/java` and used it as `$java_home -jvm_args -jar $picard [COMMAND] [rest commands]` and this works. But I would appreciate a cleaner advice.